# Publish container app by Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, iptables

i'am trying to expose to Internet an application that is running on docker container (bitwarden).
I'am using NGINX as RP that is "NOT" running on docker container but directly in host.
Container is running as follow (0.0.0.0:8005->80/tcp)
I can access to container inside LAN by http://ip_host:8005 without problem (so docker cont. is working fine).

Nginx relevant code to expose to Intenet is follow:

`

```
server {
listen 5555 ssl;
server_name domain.dom.com ;
fastcgi_param domain.dom.com $host;
autoindex off;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.dom.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.dom.com/privkey.pem;
ssl off;
ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log            /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log            /var/log/nginx/error.log;

if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ )
{
return 444;
}

if ($host !~ ^(domain.dom.com)$ ) {
return 444;
}

if ( $http_referer ~* (babes|forsale|girl|jewelry|love|nudit|organic|poker|porn|sex|teen) )
{
return 403;
}

location / {
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_pass              http://192.168.1.251:8005;
proxy_read_timeout  90;
}
}
```

`

My Problem is that i cannot access container app from Internet (by https://domain.dom.com:5555). I always receive, from NGINX server, an 504 Error code (so, server TimeOut).
What is wrong? How can I investigate deeper?
Regards

P.S. Just to be clear on same RP i'am publishing other services (by different ports. i.e. NodeRed) and all is working fine.

LOGS:

`

```
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: accept on 0.0.0.0:5555, ready: 0
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: posix_memalign: 01288710:256 @16
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 accept: X.X.X.X:52889 fd:14
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 event timer add: 14: 60000:73519165
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 reusable connection: 1
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 epoll add event: fd:14 op:1 ev:80002001
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http check ssl handshake
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http recv(): 1
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 https ssl handshake: 0x16
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 tcp_nodelay
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 ssl get session: 52528FFC:32
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL server name: "domain.dom.com"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL ALPN supported by client: h2
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL ALPN supported by client: http/1.1
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL ALPN selected: http/1.1
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL_get_error: 2
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 reusable connection: 0
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL handshake handler: 0
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 ssl new session: AE04A10F:32:153
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 reusable connection: 1
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http wait request handler
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 posix_memalign: 0128E970:256 @16
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 malloc: 012E18E8:1024
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL_read: 382
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL_read: -1
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 SSL_get_error: 2
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 reusable connection: 0
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 posix_memalign: 0128F700:4096 @16
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http process request line
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http request line: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http uri: "/"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http args: ""
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http exten: ""
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http process request header line
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http header: "Host: domain.dom.com:5555"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http header: "Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http header: "DNT: 1"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http header done
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 event timer del: 14: 73519165
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 generic phase: 0
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script var
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script var: "GET"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script regex: "^(GET|HEAD|POST)$"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [notice] 12025#12025: *1 "^(GET|HEAD|POST)$" matches "GET", client: X.X.X.X, server: domain.dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.dom.com:5555"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script if
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script if: false
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script var
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script var: "domain.dom.com"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script regex: "^(domain.dom.com|montefato.homepc.it)$"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [notice] 12025#12025: *1 "^(domain.dom.com)$" matches "domain.dom.com", client: X.X.X.X, server: domain.dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.dom.com:5555"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script if
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script if: false
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script var
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script regex: "(babes|forsale|girl|jewelry|love|nudit|organic|poker|porn|sex|teen)"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [notice] 12025#12025: *1 "(babes|forsale|girl|jewelry|love|nudit|organic|poker|porn|sex|teen)" does not match "", client: X.X.X.X, server: domain.dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.dom.com:5555"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script if
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script if: false
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 test location: ~ "/"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 using configuration "/"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 generic phase: 5
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 generic phase: 6
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 generic phase: 7
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 access phase: 8
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 access phase: 9
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 access phase: 10
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 access phase: 11
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 post access phase: 12
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 generic phase: 13
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 generic phase: 14
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 generic phase: 15
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http init upstream, client timer: 0
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 epoll add event: fd:14 op:3 ev:80002005
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 posix_memalign: 01317B60:4096 @16
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script copy: "Host"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script var: "domain.dom.com"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script copy: "X-Real-IP"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script var: "X.X.X.X"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-For"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script var: "X.X.X.X"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Proto"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script var: "https"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script copy: "Connection"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script copy: "close"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script copy: ""
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http script copy: ""
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http proxy header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http proxy header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http proxy header: "Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http proxy header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http proxy header: "DNT: 1"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http proxy header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http proxy header:
"GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: domain.dom.com
X-Real-IP: X.X.X.X
X-Forwarded-For: X.X.X.X
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Connection: close
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http cleanup add: 01290650
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 get rr peer, try: 2
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 get rr peer, current: 012D43C0 -1
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 stream socket 15
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 epoll add connection: fd:15 ev:80002005
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 connect to 192.168.1.251:8005, fd:15 #2
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http upstream connect: -2
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 posix_memalign: 0128E7F0:128 @16
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 event timer add: 15: 60000:73519255
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http finalize request: -4, "/?" a:1, c:2
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http request count:2 blk:0
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http run request: "/?"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http upstream request: "/?"
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http upstream send request handler
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http upstream send request
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 http upstream send request body
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 chain writer buf fl:1 s:455
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 chain writer in: 01290680
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 writev: 455 of 455
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 chain writer out: 00000000
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 event timer del: 15: 73519255
2020/08/06 12:01:16 [debug] 12025#12025: *1 event timer add: 15: 90000:73549265`
```

Having more troubleshooting i found issue is with iptables rules. If i flush all rules, everything works.

Here is my conf (iptableas). Does anyone can help me?

`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       24  5556 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set blacklist src
2        0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 23,79 tcp flags:0x3F/0x02 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "PortScan >SYN scan trap:"
3        0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x01 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "PortScan > FIN scan "
4        0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "PortScan > XMAS-ALL scan "
5        0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x37 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "PortScan > XMAS-PSH scan "
6        0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x29 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "PortScan > XMAS scan "
7        0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00 limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "PortScan > Null scan "
8        0     0 LOG        udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 6/hour burst 1 length 0:28 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "PortScan >0 length udp "
9        0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            length 0:28 /* Drop UDP packet with no content */
10       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW /* Drop TCP connection not starting by SYN */
11       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
12       9   456 SYN-FLOOD  tcp  --  wlan0  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x17/0x02
13       0     0 DROP       all  -f  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
14       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x17
15       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x03/0x03
16       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x06
17    9966 1756K FIREWALL   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     6293 5657K DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2     6293 5657K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3     3342 2876K ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4      119  8743 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5     2832 2772K ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
6        6  2196 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
7        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-009dee4ec221  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
8        0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      br-009dee4ec221  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
9        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-009dee4ec221 !br-009dee4ec221  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-009dee4ec221 br-009dee4ec221  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
11       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set blacklist src
12       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
13       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 8974 packets, 1356K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        2   168 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2        2   168 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID

Chain FIREWALL (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     8240 1068K ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2       98 10254 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 limit: avg 5/sec burst 5 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3 state NEW
7        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11 state NEW
8        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 13 state NEW
9        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 14 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
10       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
11       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0           
12       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       169.254.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           
13      89  7368 DROP       all  --  *      *       172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0           
14       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0           
15       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
16       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       192.168.10.0/24      0.0.0.0/0           
17       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       224.0.0.0/4          0.0.0.0/0           
18    1437  651K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4         
19       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       240.0.0.0/5          0.0.0.0/0           
20       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            240.0.0.0/5         
21      14  5124 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/8            0.0.0.0/0           
22       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/8           
23       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.0/24    
24      34  6160 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            255.255.255.255     
25       0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 17
26       0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 13
27       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
28       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x04/0x04 limit: avg 2/sec burst 2
29       2    88 TRUSTED_LAN  all  --  *      *       192.168.100.1        0.0.0.0/0           
30      49  7248 TRUSTED_LAN  all  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
31       3   192 TRUSTED_WAN  all  --  *      *      !192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
32      45  7072 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain TRUSTED_LAN (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:57443 
2        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:57444 
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:514 
4        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1880 
5        4   176 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1883
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9092 
7        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8086 
8        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000 
9        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8888 
10       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25 
11       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9847 
12       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:45001 
13       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:45002 
14       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:45003 
15       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:45004 
16       2    88 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.100.1        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22

Chain TRUSTED_WAN (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        3   192 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5555

Chain SYN-FLOOD (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        9   456 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 1/sec burst 4
2        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        4   256 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "****DOCKER****"
2        6   312 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9000
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:8000
4       18   936 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:80
5       37  1924 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:80
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:53
7       52  3375 ACCEPT     udp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           udp dpt:53

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     2832 2772K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-009dee4ec221 !br-009dee4ec221  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3     6293 5657K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      880  871K LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "****DOCKER-USER****"
2     6293 5657K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-009dee4ec221  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3     2832 2772K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

`

Comment: nginx and docker container are in the same server ? right ?

Comment: Yes! same host.

Comment: please show the error logs ?

Comment: Updated post with logs taken from NGINX

Comment: Hi Thanh Nguyen Van, i don't know why but cannot see comments replies anymore! Seams deleted!!. Can you please write again your last replied?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Just to help someone else, i had to add following iptables rules, on my FIREWALL chain:

`-A FIREWALL -s 172.17.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "**DOCKER** containers" -j ACCEPT`

So, right full chain now result like following:

`Chain FIREWALL (1 references) num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination          1    11911 1366K ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 2      126 13159 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 limit: avg 5/sec burst 5 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED 6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3 state NEW 7        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11 state NEW 8        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 13 state NEW 9        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 14 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 10       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 11     383 1402K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0            /* **DOCKER** containers */ 12       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0            13       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       169.254.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0            14      99  7847 DROP       all  --  *      *       172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0            15       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0            16       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            17       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       192.168.10.0/24      0.0.0.0/0            18       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       224.0.0.0/4          0.0.0.0/0            19    1928  878K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4          20       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       240.0.0.0/5          0.0.0.0/0            21       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            240.0.0.0/5          22      14  5124 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/8            0.0.0.0/0            23       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/8            24       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.0/24     25      27  4931 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            255.255.255.255      26       0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 17 27       0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 13 28       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 29       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x04/0x04 limit: avg 2/sec burst 2 30       1    44 TRUSTED_LAN  all  --  *      *       192.168.100.1        0.0.0.0/0            31     140 13569 TRUSTED_LAN  all  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            32      29  1848 TRUSTED_WAN  all  --  *      *      !192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            33     136 13393 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0`